# Complete Form Token Use Example: Secure storage / retrieval / use of form token PHP

Tags: php, forms, security, token

I have browsed/read numerous posts on the subject, got a lot of information (my head is spinning), but few solid (this is how its done properly) answers.

I have several forms on my website, each of which I would like to "secure" using form tokens.

My question is, what is the "secure enough" solution for creating, storing, and retrieving these tokens so that I can be sure the form can be trusted and so that it cannot be exploited by malicious users?  There has got to be some sort of accepted "best practice" framework for such a task, I just can't seem to find it; only partial, don't do this, recommendations, without examples of how to do it properly.

1. What type of hashing algorithm / encryption should be used to create the token?
2. Should the token be stored as part of the session, in a cookie, or in its own database?
3. Any other useful information regarding the proper way to secure forms with tokens?

I am concerned with the upmost security as I plan to eventually use the framework in a sales site.

TIA

Edit: Is the link in the comment posted by sємsєм the generally accepted "good-enough" practice?

Comment: Checkout this tutorial: http://css-tricks.com/serious-form-security/

Comment: @sємsєм: Thanks for the link, seems fairly straightforward, but I thought I read somewhere that the token should not be stored as part of the session; maybe it was that the session_id should not be used as the token?

Comment: what could I add to this tutorial is using another hashing algorithm other than `md5` let we say `sha1` for example and adding a salt or random string to uniqueid.

Comment: _“but I thought I read somewhere that the token should not be stored as part of the session”_ – where _else_ would you store it? Session is the safest place, where the value can not be manipulated from the outside.

Comment: The approach described there has one downside though: Let the user open multiple tabs containing forms generated that way, and the token in the session would be overwritten – so only the “last” form could successfully validate its token, the others would generate an error. Solution to that: Generate a random form id as well, and store the token in the session under that form id, and put the form id into the form using a second hidden field. That way each instance of your form(s) can have its own token, and they don’t interfere.

Comment: @CBroe: Good point and solution with the random form id.  Basically what I was after.  I do not want to simply use another's framework thinking it is iron-clad prior to finding/filling the holes, better security through scrutiny.

Comment: [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) is generally a very good resource for all things related to security of web sites/applications; and for this matter, they recommend the token approach as well: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#General_Recommendation:_Synchronizer_Token_Pattern

Comment: @CBroe: Yeah, read through a bunch of their info, not only pertaining to form tokens, but CSRF in general, XSS, etc.  Like I said, head is spinning.  The tut posted by sємsєм put laid out the framework suggested by OWASP with a more complete example rather than just saying this is what you do, it helped me to see the full example.  Thank's for the link though.